# What does this mean - "Normal error distribution has a support covering the entire line"?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-transformation

I came across the aforesaid phrase in a research paper. It was concerning the Box-Cox transformation. It said that the transformation is incompatible with the normal error distribution for the well known "truncation problem". Nonetheless, that is not my concern. ***I want to know what exactly the aforementioned phrase means?***

Comment: A random variable with a normal distribution can take any real value. The [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of a distribution is (the closure of) the values it can take

Comment: Please [search our site for answers.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=distribution%20support%20closure)

Comment: Thank you @Henry for your response. Could you please explain me the concept of "truncation error" also?